# spark data frame: how to show only those row records that have more than X number of reviews?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using amazon video game review dataset.[image: k]

It's a table of reviews, for each product(product id) many customers leave ratings of 1-5 stars.

I want to compute average review for every product_id. I group by product id and see how many reviews are left by customers for each product.

```
game_reviews_indexed.groupBy('product_id').count().take(10)
 #gives this result
[Row(product_id='B00TS0UKE4', count=119),
 Row(product_id='B004LQRF3Y', count=142),
 Row(product_id='B002I0K3Z2', count=518),
 Row(product_id='B002ZKTHD4', count=83),
 Row(product_id='B00BMFIXT2', count=1467),
 Row(product_id='B00XMQBA62', count=18),
 Row(product_id='B00N4ABMG4', count=136),
 Row(product_id='B00IEYG1AC', count=29),
 Row(product_id='B00TNY43ZC', count=1),
 Row(product_id='B006VB2UNM', count=1051)]
```

I need to sort out those products that only have 1 review, as it's not enough data to calculate avg review rating for a product.

this below code is not working

```
game_reviews_indexed[game_reviews_indexed.groupBy('product_id').count() > 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupBy` `product_id` and calculate `average` as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
game_reviews_indexed.groupBy("product_id").agg(F.mean('star_rating'), F.count('star_rating')).show()
```

if you want to filter out the count with < 2 then you can add filter as

```
.filter((f.col('d') < 2))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: wow, this is smart, i just learned that agg() can take more than 1 arg! you make 2 new columns - both the avg and count